# DBSCAN Clustering (Python) - exporting the Iris data set with a new column

Tags: dbscan

I found this cal to get the relevant clustered data to a new column. Pls see the below

from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

```
X = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 2], [2, 3],
              [8, 7], [8, 8], [25, 80]])
df = pd.DataFrame(X)
clustering = DBSCAN(eps=3, min_samples=2).fit(df)
df["clusters"] = clustering.labels_
```

I have a file on this location "C:\Users\05807\Desktop\New folder (5)\FinalX.csv"

And there are text fields as well as number fields. so the columns stated in the above report are,

"Sepal_length","Sepal_width","Petal_length","Petal_width" , "Species_name","Species_No","ID","K-Means","Hierarchical"

So I need to get a new column after "Hierarchical" column named "DBSCAN". That should contain  which cluster is which as per to DBSCAN Clustering. that means Cluster 1, cluster 2 o cluster 3. (I need the clustering output in to columns in a new CSV)

This is basically total iris data set with added two more columns. There are 150 rows and i want to export all to a new file with that additional DBSCAN column

Thanks

Comment: Anyone there to help???